# How to add the condition if a cell value is not an email address in Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My following code is working fine but the issue is, I want to add a third condition range.getCell(i, 3) value is not an email address, then the corresponding row will be deleted. How to fix it?

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("A4").getValue();
  //retrieve the start date to use as desired
  var startDate = dashboard.getRange("B4").getDisplayValue();
  var endDate = dashboard.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  //chose the range within the specified dates, for this first locate the date column
  var startRow = 2;
  var dateColumn = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var dates = dateColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var firstRow = dates.indexOf(startDate)+startRow;
  var lastRow = dates.lastIndexOf(endDate)+startRow;
  //now get the range between (and including) those rows
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, lastRow-firstRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn());

    var deleteRows = 0;      

    for (var i = range.getHeight(); i >= 1; i--){
        if(range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank() || range.getCell(i, 3).isBlank()
           **|| range.getCell(i, 3) IS NOT AN EMAIL Address){**
           sheet.deleteRow(range.getCell(i, 1).getRow());
           deleteRows++;
        }
        else{
         if(range.getCell(i, 6).isBlank()){
           range.getCell(i, 6).setValue(sheetName);
           range.getCell(i, 1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");   
         }      
       }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this line but doesn't work: if(range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank() || range.getCell(i, 3).isBlank() || !(range.getCell(i, 3).getValue().indexOf("@")>-1)){ }

Comment: what is `range`. Could you please define it ?

Comment: @Marios please check the range at the modified post as it requires more lines to make clear about the range definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have access to your sheet, it is really difficult for me to undestand if the rest of the code works.

But I managed to replicate part of your example and created the following code snippet which you can use instead of your code after `range`:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-firstRow+1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var deleteRows = 0;      
 
  for (var i = data.length-1; i >= 1; i--){
    if(data[i][0] == '' || data[i][2] == '' || !data[i][2].toString().includes('@')){  
      sheet.deleteRow(i+firstRow)
      deleteRows++;
    }
    else if(data[i][5] == '') {
    sheet.getRange(i+firstRow,6).setValue('sheetName');
    sheet.getRange(i+firstRow,1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");  
    }  
  }
```

Comment: I checked minutely and the third condition[ !data[i][2].includes('@') ] is not working.

Comment: please note that most of the time Column3, that is data[i][2] contains geolocation like this 23.7896641, 89.4224548 type values. It does not contain '@' so these rows need to be deleted. Is indexOf() or includes() works for integar values as geolocation might be integar I think

Comment: @TamjidTaha please provide a copy of your sheet. Remove all the sensitive information and give me a couple of examples.

Comment: Sorry I was not sure why it was not working. Now it is fine. Thanks

Comment: could you please check my latest post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549880/how-to-insert-the-email-address-by-querying-corresponding-id-using-google-app-sc